# Cannot start an activity using intent. Shows white screen and goes to the firstActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

want to send two string variables from secondActivity to thirdActivity using intents. It works properly in android 10 (APi 29 and above). But on android lower than it just shows a white screen for a second and goes to the firstActivity without going to the thirdActivity. but the saving stuffs works fine.

`on the secondActivity.kt`

```
    private fun save() {

         //Does saving stuff....then should go to the next Activity....

      try{
            val finIntent = Intent(this@Details_Activity, Finish_Activity::class.java)
            finIntent.putExtra("thePathName", thePath)
            finIntent.putExtra("theName", name)
            startActivity(finIntent)
            finish() }
            catch (e: NoSuchMethodException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Toast.makeText(this,e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }
```

`on the thirdActivity.kt`

```
    val name = intent.getStringExtra("theName")
    congrats_Text.text = ("Congratulations, $name !")

    val path = intent.getStringExtra("thePathName")
    path_Text.text = path.toString()
```

`I'm getting,`

```
    ``2020-10-05 20:54:20.582 20654-20654/? W/ReflectionUtils: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MessageQueue#enableMonitor()#bestmatch
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:338)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:375)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.callMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:800)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.tryCallMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:818)
        at android.os.BaseLooper.enableMonitor(BaseLooper.java:47)
        at android.os.Looper.prepareMainLooper(Looper.java:112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
2020-10-05 20:54:20.800 20654-20654/com.Something.fresume I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Something.fresume-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Something.fresume-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]``
```

`on verbose`

```
W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lx@df0e0cd
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1297)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1520)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:658)
        at ci.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203615050@20.36.15 (040406-0):1)
        at ci.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203615050@20.36.15 (040406-0):6)
        at ly.A(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203615050@20.36.15 (040406-0):10)
        at li.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203615050@20.36.15 (040406-0):3)
        at ec.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203615050@20.36.15 (040406-0):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at jb.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203615050@20.36.15 (040406-0):6)``
```

`On error,`

```
E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
```

Comment: Check logcat, there is exception probably

Comment: You should see an exception with stacktrace in the logcat. Edit your question and paste the exception and stacktrace there and we can help.

Comment: Sir @DavidWasser , Getting an exception 'W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lx@9090aa6' How do i solve it...

Comment: You edit your question and paste the contents of the exception message with stacktrace into your question. The stacktrace will tell you in what method and at what line the exception occurs. Paste that code also in your question.

Comment: Sir @DavidWasser, I have edited the question to my knowledge. It doesn't even run the catch statement as it works fine but problem in going to other Activity is still continuing. Is there any other simple way to do this using intents ?

Comment: @DavidWasser Sir can you help me ?

Comment: @Autocrab Sir can you help me?

Comment: Not really. I can't tell from the exceptions you've posted which, if any, are associated with your app. You've got obfuscated code here that makes it difficult to troubleshoot remotely. You need to add more debug logging or use a debugger. Sorry.